# I need to migrate a Java project (includes swings,servlets etc) existing in JBuilder to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, migration, m2eclipse, code-migration, jbuilder

I need to migrate a Java project (includes swings,servlets etc) existing in JBuilder to Eclipse.Any references or documentation or guidelines will be useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it contains servlets, I'd suggest you start by creating a new `Dynamic Web Application` [file > new project > web > Dynamic...]. The project folder will contain a `src` and a `WebContent` folder. I haven't worked w/ JBuilder, but I assume that you'll have your application files broadly divided along these 2 primary folders. Copy all the files contained within the corresponding JBuilder source folder into the `src` folder, and the web-based files into the `WebContent` folder.

The dependencies you can add into a lib folder under the WEB-INF folder [if that's already not the case]. The `lib` folder is not created by default so you'll need to create it.

That should get you going. Hope that helps. Write in if there are any clarifications or deadends you face.